# Power BI - Incrementing Week Numbers across years using M-Query

Tags: powerbi

I have a column called as Submitted_Date in my table.

I am looking to create a column called as Week Number in my table.

This Week Number should be incrementing across the years. It should take the minimum date across the column date and take the first date of that particular year to start week number generation.

For example, if it says 1 for 2016 first week then it should say 55 (or 54) for 2017 first week and not 1 again.

How to do this using MQuery ?

```
Submitted_Date
1/22/2016
2/27/2017
```

So, in this case it will take 1/22/2016 as the minimum date and it will start generating week numbers from the first date of 2016. So, 1/1/2017 (Sunday) is not 1 but 53 or 54.

[image]

**Update :-**

I have got something like this to work for me now. But the date (2015-12-28) is hardcoded inside. This date needs to be dynamic, as this is nothing but the beginning of the first week of 1-1-2016

```
let
    StartDate = List.Min(Submitted_Requests[Submitted_Date]),
    EndDate = List.Max(Submitted_Requests[Submitted_Date]),
    StartYear = Date.Year(StartDate),
    ListDates = List.Dates(StartDate, Number.From(EndDate - StartDate)+1, #duration(1,0,0,0)),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(ListDates, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "SubmittedDateReference"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"SubmittedDateReference", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Submitted Week Number", each Number.RoundUp((Duration.Days(Duration.From([SubmittedDateReference]- Date.FromText("2015-12-28"))) + 1) / 7)),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Submitted Week Number", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace `Date.FromText("2015-12-28")` with the appropriate dynamic date expression. Possibly something `Date.StartOfYear(StartDate)`, for example.

I'm not sure why you used `2015-12-28` in particular, so you might need to add an offset like `Date.DayOfWeek(Date.StartOfYear(StartDate))` if you want to start the week on a particular day.

Comment: Thanks and this helps me to move further.